# iOS 8 keyboard resolution

Tags: ios, keyboard, resolution

For my app I am observing that the keyboard that appears against an editable field (UITextView for example) is larger as compared to the keyboard that normally appears in any other app (for example while editing the Contacts etc). The keys are larger so are the gaps between the keys. Any idea how to resolve this and get the keyboard resolution back to the same as that of the Contacts app for example.

I also observe that the Navigation buttons have bolder texts as compared to navigation buttons on other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, I added a launch screen to my app and that led to the use of proper resolution when it comes to keyboard, navigation menu etc on the iPhone 6.

Seems, to make use of the highest resolution on an iPhone 6 (and above), you will have to have a launch screen.

If a launch image is used instead, what I was having is the small screen app (read running on iPhone 4 / 5) was being magnified to fit into iPhone 6.